# How to create Graph by specifying the range of x and multi Y axis

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create line semi log graphs using macro in excel 2007.
where only one x axis (sheet1!A4:A18) and multi y axis. 
I like to specify the column no;s and also want to create one button on wich i can click and generate the graph.

I am using excel 2007

please help me.

Comment: Record a macro and a have a try at the vba yourself. This site is not about providing a specific answer to your problem its about learning.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Macro Recorder? Turn it on, make your graph once manually, stop the recorder. Edit the resulting code. Save you lots of time.